# How to switch off autoplay when displaying facebook wall (includes videos) on web-page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

I am using the drupal module https://drupal.org/project/facebook_wall to pull a facebook wall onto my website. The wall contains facebook videos, and all of these start, so autoplay must be set to on by default.

Is there a way to pull the wall with autoplay switched off?

The module requests the facebook page using curl and the graph api:

```
$api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . FB_PAGE_NAME . '/posts?access_token=' . FB_ACCESS_TOKEN . '&limit=10'
```

Changing the url to this one doesn't change anything:

```
$api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . FB_PAGE_NAME . '/posts?access_token=' . FB_ACCESS_TOKEN . '&limit=10&autoplay=off'
```

The url of one of the videos is constructed like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" width="400" height="250" src="https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-ash3/v/xxxxx_n.mp4?oh=yyy&oe=zzz&__gda__=aaa" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In the original version of the question, I had entered here the "embed" line that is displayed on the finished page. I then realized that it must have been embedded through the iframe tag, which is what the module pulls from facebook.

I changed the iframe tag to:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" width="400" height="250" src="https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-ash3/v/xxxxx_n.mp4?autoplay=false&oh=yyy&oe=zzz&__gda__=aaa" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The good news is: the video doesn't start.
The bad news is: instead of the video, the following error message is displayed:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.bcb754b8.1377899267.aa42993
```

Any idea what to possibly do to switch the player off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the argument

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-ash3/v/xxxx_n.mp4?oh=yyy&oe=zzz&__gda__=aaa" type="video/mp4">
```

to

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-ash3/v/xxxx_n.mp4?oh=yyy&oe=zzz&__gda__=aaa" type="video/mp4" autoplay="false">
```

to do this, I think  maybe you can try the following code

```
$api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . FB_PAGE_NAME . '/posts?access_token=' . FB_ACCESS_TOKEN . '&autoplay=false';
```

Let me know if that way works.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding &autoplay=false to the api_url doesn't have any effect. I'll try to parse out the embed line and will add the autoplay option there.

Comment: I realized that only the iframe tag gets pulled. Added more information to the query.

Comment: Instead of autoplay=false, it needs autoplay=0.

Comment: Thanks for your own answer